# Failed to upload azure functions app from vscode when using pytorch

Tags: python, azure, pytorch, azure-functions

I am trying to upload a function app, that contains pytorch, from vscode, but I fail. The output says the following:

```
3:51:18 PM CartProvider: Running pip install...
3:51:25 PM CartProvider: Done in 7 sec(s).
3:51:25 PM CartProvider: [18:51:18+0000] Collecting azure-functions
3:51:25 PM CartProvider: [18:51:18+0000]   Downloading azure_functions-1.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)
3:51:25 PM CartProvider: [18:51:19+0000] Collecting torch
3:51:25 PM CartProvider: [18:51:19+0000]   Downloading torch-2.2.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (755.5 MB)
3:51:25 PM CartProvider: "2024-03-04 18:51:25"|ERROR|[18:51:18+0000] Collecting azure-functions
3:51:25 PM CartProvider: [18:51:18+0000]   Downloading azure_functions-1.18.0-py3-none-any.whl (173 kB)
3:51:25 PM CartProvider: [18:51:19+0000] Collecting torch
3:51:25 PM CartProvider: [18:51:19+0000]   Downloading torch-2.2.1-cp310-cp310-manylinux1_x86_64.whl (755.5 MB) | Exit code: 137 | Please review your requirements.txt | More information: https://aka.ms/troubleshoot-python
3:51:27 PM CartProvider: /opt/Kudu/Scripts/starter.sh oryx build /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted -o /home/site/wwwroot --platform python --platform-version 3.10.4 -p packagedir=.python_packages/lib/site-packages
3:51:31 PM CartProvider: Deployment failed.
```

Here is my requirements.txt file:

`azure-functions torch sentence-transformers pandas`

it's supposed to have every dependency in a newline, but I'm new to this.

My code is a simple http trigger with an input binding, the function is given a list of product names, and it returns the most semantically similar products within the input database. The code works perfectly when testing in a local environment.

Please help :)

Below is the function_app.py code:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code which you have tried?

Answer (score 0):

I have created Http trigger function with runtime stack python. I have added some sample code about Pandas and Torch below:

**function code:**

```
import logging
import azure.functions as func
import torch
import pandas as pd

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')

    # Sample data for demonstration
    data = {'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B': [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]}
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Create a PyTorch tensor from pandas DataFrame
    tensor = torch.tensor(df.values)

    # Perform a simple operation using PyTorch
    result = tensor.sum().item()

    # Construct response message
    if result:
        return func.HttpResponse(f"The sum of all elements in the tensor is: {result}", status_code=200)
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
            "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. However, there was an issue calculating the result.",
            status_code=200
        )
```

**requirement.txt:**

```
azure-functions
torch
sentence-transformers
pandas
```

- The code runs successfully in local environment. check below:

**Output:**
[image]

while deploying the above function into azure portal i am also getting same error.

[image]

- I have tried another approach like publishing the function into azure by using this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/create-first-function-cli-powershell?tabs=windows%2Cazure-cli%2Cbrowser).

**Deployment status:**

[image]

[image]

- I have tried with zip deployment method also, check this [DOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push?tryIt=true&source=docs#code-try-0)

```
az functionapp deployment source config-zip -g <resource_group> -n <app_name> --src <zip_file_path>
```

[image]

- While deploying the function into azure by using zip deployment ensure that basic authentication have enabled and until completed the deployment check the basic authentication. check below for enabling.

[image]